# Which std::string constructor is being called here?

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to construct a string in C++ as below.

```
const char *cstring = "abcd";
const string cppstr = string(cstring, cstring + strlen(cstring));
```

This is working fine and cppstr has the value "abcd" even though it doesn't match with any of the string constructors specified in the standard. Can any one please let me know which constructor of string is invoked in this particular case.

Answer (score 5):

There is a templated constructor that takes as its input two InputIterators. (See [the cppreference.org reference, constructor (6)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)). Raw C++ pointers meet all the requirements of InputIterators (in fact, they're RandomAccessIterators). Therefore, calling

```
string(cstring, cstring + strlen(cstring)
```

invokes this constructor. That constructor works by iterating across the range of the elements delineated by the iterator and constructing a string as a copy of those elements.

As a note, you can also just write

```
const string cppstr{cstring, cstring + strlen(cstring)};
```

here instead of assigning `cppstr` a value.

Comment: Or even just `const string cppstr{cstring};`

Comment: @rici : if I use const string cppstr(cstring), the created string will contain '\0' in it.

Comment: @kadina Are you sure about that? The constructor is designed to stop as soon as it hits a null terminator.

Comment: @rici : I remember I saw that. But I will check and update.

Comment: @kadina: C++ strings are always followed by a NUL, but the NUL is not part of the string. The intention is to simplify interoperability with C (so the library doesn't need to copy the string when you call the `c_str()` method. But you can verify that (if the string contains no NULs), `s.size()` is exactly the same as `strlen(s.c_str())`.